# A live counter that shows the current online people ( PHP and jquery )

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to make a counter for **current** online users. but I can't find an efficient way to do this right away. I was already thinking about an automatic reload, but that's not too efficient. 
I want the code output to be =>

```
<p>Current online: <span id="counter">---</span></p>

=> Current online: ---
```

I can reload automatically the span element with jquery but I need the counter script to check the current online people. If a database is requerd I prefer a simple file on the server for that. Does somebody have an idea how I can figure this out?

I've tried =>

See every request for 2 minutes online and then the Page automatic reloads to check if the page is still open if it isn't then he is offline but I'm looking for a better and faster interact system but I can't think on something. I don't ask for code, but just for an idea of how I can get it to work. Thank You

Comment: What have you already tried to do? What are the errors you encountered? StackOverflow is not a free coding service. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I changed the code! I hope you can help me think of a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made it work!
I use this script to load 2 PHP files to change the number with +1 of -1.

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
        // async: false will make the AJAX synchronous in case you're using jQuery
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost/Onload.php',
            data: { ajax_data : 22 },
            async: false
        });
    });
    $(window).on('unload', function() {
        // async: false will make the AJAX synchronous in case you're using jQuery
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost/Onclose.php',
            data: { ajax_data : 22 },
            async: false
        });
    });
```

The other 2 files here => 
Onload.php:

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("Counter.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$before = fread($myfile,filesize("Counter.txt"));
fclose($myfile);
$myfile = fopen("Counter.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$after = $before + 1;
echo "$before : $after";
fwrite($myfile, $after);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Onclose.php:

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("Counter.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$before = fread($myfile,filesize("Counter.txt"));
fclose($myfile);
$myfile = fopen("Counter.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$after = $before - 1;
echo "$before : $after";
fwrite($myfile, $after);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Now you only have to make the script to read out the txt file and print this in the span element. I hope I'm helpfull to you!